# What is wrong with this Code? This Code is from a Book about learning C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and as I mentioned above there is a problem in the Code and I don't know what causes this problem. This is not my Code the Code is from a Book about C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /* Declaration */
    int amount;
    double price;

    /* Input 1 */
    printf("Amount: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    /* Input 2 */
    printf("Price in Dollar: ");
    scanf("&lf", &price);

    /* Print */
    printf("Amount: &d", amount);
    printf("Price &lf Dollar", price);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please state what your problem is.

Comment: I think the point of a book that's supposed to teach you C is that you try the code out and go through the process of debugging it, rather than just asking what's wrong online. If you did try anything, then you should share that in the question. Show us your debugging steps and error messages or bad output you encountered.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that code. Unless you tell us what this code is supposed to do which it isn't doing, there is nothing wrong with it. One thing that **might** be wrong with it (just guessing) is that `printf` is not starting a new line unless you tell it to do so, so the last two prints print on the same single line. If `printf` is supposed to start a new line, it requires you to print a newline character (`"\n"`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo:

Instead of

```
scanf("&lf", &price);
```

it should be

```
scanf("%lf", &price);
```

And instead of

```
printf("Price &lf Dollar", price);
```

it should be

```
printf("Price %lf Dollar", price);
```